# Installing .NET CF 3.5 side by side with standard framework

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework

We have a machine that needs .NET Compact Framework installed and now we need to install standard .NET Framework 3.5.
Any problems or known issues with installing both frameworks together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems. I do this for my development on both Windows Mobile devices and Desktop applications on the same machine.